# Large File Upload using Web API

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I have a winforms application that sends a multipart file to webAPI. 
It works  fine for servers here in the office. But the same isnt working when the server is in UTAH. For small files, it is OK. But not for large files.

Here is the code where we use for uploading:

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        // Save document to disk
        String rootPath = _repository.Document_AddDirectory(documentID, User);
        FileStreamProvider provider = new FileStreamProvider(_repository, rootPath, documentID, User);

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Define "isn't working". Have you tried tracing (Fiddler etc)?

Comment: Fiddler? I tried using it, but could not capture the event. The error says Client Disconnected. It doesn't work with UTAH server.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some web.config settings you might check on your server in Utah that could be the cause of a large file size failing on one server while working on another.

[httpRuntime maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - The size limit for a request stream.  The default is 4096 (4mb).

[httpRuntime executionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - The number of seconds before a request is automatically shut down

Comment: Raz - a guess and a followup question does not belong as an "Answer". I suggest you use comments for this type of response.

Comment: Thanks Ekoo.  I was wondering why I got the down vote.  Apparently though I cant comment until my rep score is above 50.  Stack overflow wont let me.  So Answer is all I can do.  I apologize if that was inappropriate.

Comment: You could improve your answer by including specific details on what web.config settings may help, where to put them and what values to use.

Comment: Good advice.  And thanks again for explaining why I received the downvote instead of just voting without comment.

Comment: Web Config in WebApi has the settings set to Max. Always the error says Client Disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

this has to do with HttpClient. I used a filestreamcontent , which delayed the process.
So, I changed to Bytearraycontent and moved all the process to async version.